# Does single-player client render distance affect server view distance?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

This is a question about single-player Minecraft.

A few years ago, the server and client were split up in single player.

Does changing the client render distance in single player change the server view distance to the same value?

Or is the server view distance always 10 in single player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client and server render distance are the same in Singleplayer.

Otherwise for example a render distance of 32 wouldn't be useful at all.